# "Rails" is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using ruby 2.0.0 and my command says I am using rails 4.0.2

On the RoR tutorial I need to:

`rails generate controller StaticPages home help --no-test-framework`

However the command response is

`rails' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Please help!!

Comment: Are you inside the Rails application directory?

Comment: *What* command says you're using Rails 4.0.2?

Comment: Using the windows command prompt

Comment: That helps, but that isn't what Dave Newton asked, he asked what command was telling you your rails version.  You have to be very specific and verbose if you want help with something you don't understand.

Comment: Rails -v in the command prompt

Comment: Then you're fat-fingering something and `rails'` is *precisely* what you're typing, and it's not a command. Just type `rails`. If you can run `rails` to get the version, then you can run `rails` to generate a controller.